# is there some one expert with the btc recovery tool?

Tags: blockchain, blockchain.info, wallet-recovery, wallet-security, bitcoin-wallet-app

trying to use btc recovery tool , installed every thing , python 2.7 and all the required pibs . followed tutorials . actually i need to find second password so am using the command i.e c:\python27\python btcrecover.py --wallet wallet.aes.json --utf8 --blockchain-secondpass
here it asks for main password , when i enter it ,,, it says wrong main password where i can enter to blockchain wallet using the same password . where i am going wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

either you have the wrong wallet.aes.json or you have a v1 wallet. they (blockchain.info) seem to have used three different wallet encryptions and btcrecover only work with one.